# Weird behavior using keyEquivalent on NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, nsmenuitem

I wanted to be able to set the `keyEquivalent` of an `NSMenuItem` based on an `NSString`, e.g. : <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, etc

For this, I created a method in an `NSString` category as following (debugging `NSLog`s included) :

```
- (NSDictionary*)toKeyEquivalent
{
    NSMutableDictionary* result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSArray* parts = [self componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];

    NSLog(@"parts :%@",parts);

    if ([[parts objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"key",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"mask", nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [result setValue:[parts lastObject] forKey:@"key"];

        int mask = 0;

        for (NSString* p in parts)
        {
            if ([p isEqualToString:@"CMD"])
            {
                NSLog(@"cmd");
                mask |= NSCommandKeyMask;
            }
            else if ([p isEqualToString:@"SHIFT"])
            {
                NSLog(@"shift");
                mask |= NSShiftKeyMask;
            }
            else if ([p isEqualToString:@"CTRL"])
            {
                NSLog(@"ctrl");
                mask |= NSControlKeyMask;
            }
            else if ([p isEqualToString:@"ALT"])
            {
                NSLog(@"alt");
                mask = NSAlternateKeyMask;
            }
        }

        [result setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:mask] forKey:@"mask"];

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm testing that using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

The NSLog output is :

> 2012-04-03 10:36:19.051 App[4654:903] parts :(
>       CMD,
>       R )
>
> 2012-04-03 10:36:19.052 App[4654:903] cmd
>
> 2012-04-03 10:36:19.052 App[4654:903] keyEq : {
>       key = R;
>       mask = 1048576; } - for Run

Which looks good; `mask=1048576` means `1<<20` which is equal to `NSCommandKeyMask`.

In other words, it SEEMS as if the Key Equivalent (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>) has been correctly interpreted.

**The weird thing, though, is that when the menu item finally appears, the Key Equivalent appearing next to is "<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>".... :-S**

Why is that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you pass in `r` or `R`? I think if you pass it an upper case string, it automatically adds the shift requirement.

Comment: Holy cow... Thanks A LOT! Unbelievably silly of me; simply couldn't even imagine that something like that could have had such an effect... You saved me so much time! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're passing an uppercase letter to `setKeyEquivalent:`. [The docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000265-BAJIABIH) have this to say:

> Discussion
>   This method considers the case of the letter passed to determine if it has a Shift modifier added. That is, `[item setKeyEquivalent:@"w"]` sets the key equivalent to Command-w, while `[item setKeyEquivalent:@"W"]` is Command-Shift-w.

You'll need to do a bit more processing on the entered string, and make sure that the letter is lowercase if "SHIFT" isn't present.

You should also (eventually) consider being more liberal in your accepted input -- this code won't work if the input is "Shift" or "shift", both of which are reasonable variations.

I also think that you have a bug/typo: your assignment to `mask` in the "Alt" key branch seems to be missing the OR:

```
mask = NSAlternateKeyMask;
// should be mask |= NSAlternateKeyMask;
```

Comment: Being more... "liberal" in my input is not really necessary, since I'm basically getting the input from a `plist` I have created, so no big deal; good point for the `NSAlternateKeyMask` though, it WAS a typo indeed (oh... you can't avoid them, no matter how cautious you are...) ;-)

Comment: Oh, sorry, it sounded like you were getting strings from the user.